# ".save" only inserts null values in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make a RoR application for a Hospital so it has patients, doctors, offices, etc.

The problem I'm having is that, at the patient "Sign-up", I'm not able to save the new patient in the database. In fact, despite I've checked that the attributes are ok (It's just a name and a personal ID), once the method is excecuted, in the database only appears a new row with "<null>" instead of the actual attribute values. Here's the method:

```
def pat_create

  pName = params[:name].to_s
  id    = params[:pid].to_s.to_i

  pat = Patient.where(:pID => id).first
  if pat == nil
    pat = Patient.new(:name => pName, :pID =>id)
    pat.save
  end

end
```

Also, This is the query that it constructs:

```
INSERT INTO `patients` (`created_at`, `name`, `pID`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-05-20 02:04:28', NULL, NULL, '2013-05-20 02:04:28')
```

This method is called after some other view collects the :name and :pid information in this form:

```
<%= form_tag('/page/pat_create') do %> 
  <%= text_field_tag :name, nil%> 
  <%= text_field_tag :pid, nil%> 
  <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-success") do %> 
    Register<i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> 
  <%end%> 
<%end%>
```

Needless to say, `pat.errors.empty?` is true, and so is `pat.save`.

Any idea why this happens?

Here's Patient Model:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :pID
  attr_accessor :name, :pID

  has_many :appointments
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates :name, :format => {:with=> /^[a-zA-Z\s\D]+$/}
  validates_presence_of :pID
  validates_numericality_of :pID
  validates_inclusion_of :pID, :in => 100000..9999999999   

end
```

Comment: can you post your patient model?

Comment: Call .save! and you will get an error explaining what is happening.

Comment: @Larry I just edited the post with the Patient Model, and also called .save! but got no error, where am I supposed to look at this error? Look how a patient is created [Image](https://www.facebook.com/ajax/messaging/attachment.php?attach_id=531b970d5a3293d9b0660a9e41004326&mid=mid.1369024037772%3A82c7488af722799652&hash=AQBakl0OcbYsy7wH)

Comment: If you look at the output of your rails server you should see exactly what is happening. What values it is attempting to save, if any errors happened and the save rolled back, etc.

Comment: Can you confirm that every time you try to save that you see a new entry in your database with null values?

Comment: I think I found your problem... Posting answer now.

Comment: @Larry Yes, Everytime I try to create a new Patient, a new row with nulls is created at the table

Comment: Is there a need for `attr_accessor :name, :pID`? Have you tried removing that line to see if `.save` works?

Comment: @sunxperous OMFG It worked! please post this as an answer so I thank you properly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the following line in `class Patient`:

```
attr_accessor :name, :pID
```

What happened was that [attr_accessor replaced](http://maxivak.com/attr_accessor-vs-attr_accessible-ruby-on-rails/) the two database column attributes `:name` and `:pID` (which were automatically generated) with its own, resulting in two virtual attributes, `:name` and `:pID`.

Thus, the virtual attributes were being set and validated instead of the corresponding database attributes, which resulted in no errors yet null values in the database.

Comment: A lovely answer certainly helped me out!

Answer (score -1):

Can you show us how this method is called? Also are you sure that params[:name] and params[:pid].

You have used the column :pid and :pID, as below

```
pat = Patient.where(:pID => id).first
if pat == nil
  pat = Patient.new(:name => pName, :pID =>id)  # should use pat = Patient.new(:name => pName, :pid =>id)
  pat.save
end
```

Comment: And what is in your create method in the Patient controller?

Comment: I have changed the code with your suggestion (using ":pid =>id" instead of ":pID =>id") and it raised this error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: pid".

Anyhow, it wouldn't change much since ":name => pName" remains the same, right?

Comment: And I have only one controller called page_controller, that's where this method is.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are calling this method (show the code) and the form used? This generally would be put in the Patient Controller in the create action

Comment: You need to add pid to attr_accessible in the Patient model.

Comment: @AndrésFernández using pid is better but you have to change it everywhere including your models in order for it to work.

Answer (score -1):

So in your controller your params are nil but you call `.to_s` and `.to_s.to_i` which results in an empty string "" and 0 (zero). You then save them into your database. A couple recommendations:

```
def pat_create

  pat = Patient.new(:name => params[:name], :pid =>params[:pid])
  pat.save

end
```

In addition to the uniqueness validation I would make sure your db column has a unique index on it to insure no duplicate patients.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :pid
  attr_accessor :name, :pid

  has_many :appointments
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                   length: { maximum: 50 }, 
                   format: {:with=> /^[a-zA-Z\s\D]+$/}
  validates :pid, presence: true,
                  numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                  greater_than_or_equal_to: 100000, 
                                  less_than_or_equal_to: 9999999999 },
                  uniqueness: true
end
```

If you are getting valid values this will work and if not you will see why it is not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it's still not working. Maybe it's from the database? This is really frustrating, actually

Comment: I am curious if you are having a routing issue here. Can you post what your routes look like for this action? I noticed it is not the restful create action and I am curious if it is configured as a GET request instead of a POST.

Comment: The issue is already solved, It was a matter of deleting that `attr_accessor :name, :pID` line out of the Model code. Anyhow, I have in the routes `match "/pat_create" => "page#pat_create"`, I'm almost sure it's not the appropiate way, but I don't know much about Rest...